# How to get Arduino values from a string after and before a column (character)?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am struggling to take down a string values.

This is the actual code (Doesn't Work):

```cpp
String stringValue;
String stringValue1;
int stringValue2 = 0;

stringValue = "FirstSensorReading: 456"

stringValue1 = BeforeColumn(":");
stringValue2 = AfterColumn(":");
```

The code is suppose to return the following:

```cpp
String stringValue;
String stringValue1;
int stringValue2 = 0;

stringValue = "FirstSensorReading: 456"

stringValue1 = "FirstSensorReading";
stringValue2 = 456;
```

Comment: What's the code for `BeforeColumn(":")` and `AfterColumn(":");`? Are you getting any errors, or wonky output?

Comment: Is it a question or a request?

Comment: @eyllanesc A question

Comment: @Ingenioushax I need to equal the first string to the text before the column and the second string to the value after the column.

Comment: What is the BeforeColumn or AfterColumn code?

Comment: @eyllanesc its to get the text before column, it's not a code that's whats not working.

Comment: Arduino is not C and not exactly C++. And what is your **specific** problem? What is the question?

Comment: @Olaf Your right but according to FAQ on the Arduino page "the Arduino language is merely a set of C/C++ functions", I though some C, C++ devs could help as well, Sorry if I've been wrong.

Comment: Lesson 1, 2, 3 ... 100: Don't believe what you read on the Internet (stack overflow) is the exception to the rule;-). C and C++ are distinct languages already.

Comment: @Olaf The problem with removing the C/C++ tags is that the colors in the code disappear. To me it is C/C++, it gets compiled with avr-gcc and has a (hidden) main function. But maybe a new tag (avr-c++ for example) could be created (or the existing avr-gcc) that uses the c++ syntax highlighting?

Comment: @Danny_ds: Feel free to ask on meta to enable syntax highlighting for Arduino, comments are not the place to discuss this. Simple solution is to use markdown to enable syntax highlighlighting. Nevertheless, syntax highlighting is not the reason to use the tags, but a side-effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `String` then maybe you want to use [indexOf](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringIndexOf) and [substring](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring).

```cpp
String stringValue;
String stringValue1;
int stringValue2 = 0;

stringValue = "FirstSensorReading: 456"

int index = stringValue.indexOf(':');
stringValue1 = stringValue.substring(0, index);
stringValue2 = stringValue.substring(index + 2).toInt();
```

Comment: Ellow any comments in the codes on how's it working? x)

Comment: Man, I linked two official tutorials.

Comment: OP has internet but no search engine?

Comment: @KevinDTimm xD Your funny!

Comment: @mpiatek Good track, I'll definitely give a try and come back to mark it as an answer if it suit my needs and I think it will.

Comment: @mpiatek Thanks a lot it worked. I just need to count the index then use substring king :D

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `strtok()` or `strtok_r()` - the latter is thread safe/reentrant.

Comment: Could you please give an example in your answer, it seem being the good one.

Comment: I will recommend a search for `arduino strtok` as it's better to teach a man to fish than to give a man a fish.

Comment: Holy Moses - why in wide, wide world of sports would someone down vote this?

Comment: I guess it's because it's not explaining much and on stack you suppose to explain. Wasn't me tho :P Am researching on your hint ^^

Comment: And I'm not going to write code that's available in 1B locations on the internet. I expect a modicum of effort from people who are trying to write software and usage of a search engine is lesson 1.

Comment: Sorry its not what I needed wrong answer. :( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

the function called beforeORafter() has three arguments

the first argument "str" is where you should place your string

the second argument "Target" is where you should place the word you have seperated the text with

the third argument "dataIndex"

dataIndex = 0: return data before "target"

dataIndex = 1: return data after  "target"

```
String beforeORafter(String str, String Target, int dataIndex = 0){

       int targetLength = Target.length();

       int index = str.indexOf(Target);

       String out = "";  

       if(dataIndex < 1){

           // before            //start // end
           out = str.substring(0, index);

       }else{

           // after
           out = str.substring(index + targetLength);

       }

       return out;

 }

String yourPhrase = "hello IN World";

String separatorWord = "IN";

int dataBefore = 0;
int datAfter = 1;


String before = beforeORafter(yourPhrase, separatorWord, dataBefore);


String after = beforeORafter(yourPhrase, separatorWord, datAfter);


Serial.print("before: ");
Serial.println(before);

Serial.print("after: ");
Serial.println(after);
```